# react native - assigning state to const

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-paper

I'm starting with react native, and when using a library called react native paper, I've come across a statement where the state is being assigned to a const as shown below.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Searchbar } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    firstQuery: '',
  };

  render() {
    const { firstQuery } = this.state;
    return (
      <Searchbar
        placeholder="Search"
        onChangeText={query => { this.setState({ firstQuery: query }); }}
        value={firstQuery}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Beginning of the 'Render' method, you could see const { firstQuery } = this.state;
Could someone please explain why the state is being assigned to a const named 'firstQuery', and even if it have a reason, how will the assignment correctly map the property 'firstQuery' inside the state object to the const ?

Thanks in advance. The code sample is from https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/searchbar.html#value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That syntax is not React nor React Native. It's just Javascript's syntax, called destructuring.

```
const { firstQuery } = this.state;
```

is equivalent to

```
const firstQuery = this.state.firstQuery;
```

just a short-hand shortcut syntax, you see 2 `firstQuery`*s*? People just don't want *duplication* in code, so they invented it.

---

See the *vanilla javascript* snippet below:

```js
const object = {
  name: 'Aby',
  age: 100,
}

const { name, age } = object;
// instead of 
// const name = object.name;

console.log(name, age);
console.log(object.name, object.age);

//=========================================
// imagine:
const obj = {
  veryLongPropertyNameToType: 420
}

const { veryLongPropertyNameToType } = obj;
// instead of
// const veryLongPropertyNameToType = obj.veryLongPropertyNameToType;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like another answer mentioned, it's just JavaScript syntax aka destructuring. If you're feeling confused and wished to just use the "vanilla" JavaScript syntax, you can take a look at below.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Searchbar } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    firstQuery: '',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Searchbar
        placeholder="Search"
        onChangeText={query => { this.setState({ firstQuery: query }); }}
        value={this.state.firstQuery} // <<<<<<<<<<< LOOK HERE
      />
    );
  }
}
```